# SharePoint 2013 - Sharing column

Tags: sharepoint-server, column

I want to know how I can set the "Sharing column" at the document library.
I found [this](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/cd7126df-9d97-4916-8bcf-af22e18d91fe.png) and
[this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-documents-or-folders-in-SharePoint-Server-2013-5eec8604-e9d7-4f84-bee5-1c7d8e048d8c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and there is the "Sharing column" but I dont see the sharing column in my list settings. So how can I enable this column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This column only shows on OneDrive. Switch your OneDrive and you shall see the column there where you can set who has should access the file or folder and what permission level they should have.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Is it possible to show file permissions in a column, or is this not recommend?

Comment: I have not seen myself before, and I don't think it can be done out of the box.